# reCaptcha container not loading correctly

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

For some strange reason my reCaptcha container block appears to be broken. I suspect it could be a style I set which it does not like, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is.

The link to the project is http://www.nbwindscreenrepairs.com/keytosuccess/

You will notice that the individual blocks appear to be shifted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from another forum:

```
span#recaptcha_privacy {
    display:none;
}
```

which removes the link to this page: http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.recaptchatable .recaptcha_r8_c1, .recaptchatable .recaptcha_r7_c1 {
    background-position-x: -43px;
    background-position-y: -52px;
    height: 5px;
}

img#recaptcha_reload, img#recaptcha_whatsthis_btn { 
    height: 17px !important;
}

img#recaptcha_switch_audio {
    height: 18px !important;
}
```

Preserve the `!important` to override the inline style.

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't really remember the source of this code. But it resolved the problem.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #recaptcha_area input[type="text"] {
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Place in the file where `recaptcha` present.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am late to the party , Here's wat worked for me,The code below solved my issue

```
<style type="text/css">
    .recaptchatable .recaptcha_input_area #recaptcha_response_field{
     margin: 0 !important;
     top: 12px !important;
     padding: 2px !important;

    }
</style>
```